# How do I make my Magento menu remain expanded for specific items?

Tags: css, magento, menu, expansion

For example, here is my Magento site:

http://nyctodesign.com/gulfsales/

What I want is for the 'Categories' and 'Brands' items to remain expanded (I don't want them to expand by scrolling over them with the mouse, I want them to always remain expanded).  If possible, I'd also like the items inside the expanded categories to require mouseover for expansion.

So Categories and Brands are expanded permanently, while Categories->Power Tools still requires a mouseover.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS in `/gulfsales/skin/frontend/default/theme300/css/styles.css`:

```
.level0.active .level0, .level1.active .level1, .level2.active .level2 {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works absolutely perfectly, and the directions were very precise.  Thank you so much!